# pyspark wrapper for IndexedRowMatrix multiply()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

The PySpark wrapper for the `IndexedRowMatrix` class doesn't include all the methods - specifically, the multiply() method is missing even though it's included in the Java implementation that it wraps. I tried adding it manually to PySpark/MlLib/inalg/distributed.py, as follows:

```
def multiply(self, other):
    other_java_matrix = other._java_matrix_wrapper._java_model
    java_matrix = self._java_matrix_wrapper.call("multiply", other_java_matrix)
    return IndexedRowMatrix(java_matrix)
```

However, I get the following error when I try to use this method:

> py4j.Py4JException: Method multiply([class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix]) does not exist
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is Spark version 1.6.1, so it should include this method AFAIK. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`IndexedRowMatrix` doesn't support multiplication by another `IndexedRowMatrix`. It only supports multiplication by a local `Matrix` (`mllib.linalg.Matrix`).

To multiply distributed matrices you'll have to create a wrapper around [`BlockMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix) which is at this moment (Spark 1.6) the only distributed structure in MLlib which supports multiplication by another distributed matrix.